# Problem in passing the directly variable to powershell command

Tags: powershell, set

I am new to PowerShell scripting

I have scenario I need to set group names in ADServiceAccount, for that I have saved group names in one variable:

```
$groupnames = "grp1,grp2"
$accountname = "user1"
$controller = "DC=zzabc,DC=zzadc,dc=ap,dc=com"
```

I have tried with below command but with the below command it is through error

```
Set -ADSServiceAccount -Identity $accountname -groupnames $groupnames -server $controller
```

**Error**:

```
Identity info provided in the extended attribute : 'groupnames' could not b resolves, reason:'cannot find an object with identity:'grp1,grp2' under 'DC=zzabc,DC=zzadc,dc=ap,dc=com'
```

... but IF I pass directly group names to command it will work, like below

```
Set-ADSServiceAccount -Identity $accountname -groupnames grp1,grp2 -server $controller
```

Kindly help to resolve the issue,,
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

The `-groupnames` parameter is expecting an array list of groups. Your `$groupnames = "grp1,grp2"` is creating a string, change it to create an array by doing this `$groupnames = "grp1","grp2"` and that should work for you